# Problem in displaying child form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

There are two panels in my parent form. In the right panel there is one list view. The problem is that whenever I load the child form, the child form goes back of the list view. I want to load the child form at top of the list view. I tried to set the property of list view to “send to back” in design view but it doesn’t work. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and language Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code probably would have helped decipher this question.

I'm going to assume this ListView control is DockFilled in a panel, and when you are saying you want to load a child form, you are trying to move the ListView down and show your child form inside the panel.

My attempt:

```
Dim newChild As New ChildForm
newChild.TopLevel = False
newChild.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
newChild.Dock = DockStyle.Top
Panel1.Controls.Add(newChild)
newChild.Show()
```